# Unity 2D player movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, sprite

I had my unity movement working on my computer, however when i try to play on my android it is not moving for me at all. I am sure it is probably a small error i am overlooking but i would be very appreciative of any help! I do not get any errors when i try yo run my code if that is of any assistance! I will supply the code below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

//Adding this allows us to access members of the UI namespace including Text.
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text countText;          //Store a reference to the UI Text component which will display the number of pickups collected.
    //public Text winText;          //Store a reference to the UI Text component which will display the 'You win' message.
    private double count;               //Integer to store the number of pickups collected so far.


    //Player movement controls
    private Vector3 touchPosition;  //where your finger touches screen
    private Vector3 direction;      //direction you drag sprite
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;       //Store a reference to the Rigidbody2D component required to use 2D Physics.
    public float speed = 10f;               //Floating point variable to store the player's movement speed.


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Get and store a reference to the Rigidbody2D component so that we can access it.
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

        //Initialize count to zero.
        count = 0;

        //Initialze winText to a blank string since we haven't won yet at beginning.
        //winText.text = " "; //error here??

        //Call our SetCountText function which will update the text with the current value for count.
        //SetCountText ();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            touchPosition.z = 0;
            direction = (touchPosition - transform.position);
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x , direction.y) * speed;

            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            }
        }
    }

    //OnTriggerEnter2D is called whenever this object overlaps with a trigger collider.
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
    {
        //Check the provided Collider2D parameter other to see if it is tagged "PickUp", if it is...
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("PickUp")) 
        {
            //... then set the other object we just collided with to inactive.
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            //Add one to the current value of our count variable.
            count = count + 1;

            //Update the currently displayed count by calling the SetCountText function.
            //SetCountText ();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my 2D Player Movement Controller.

Code(Character Controller) -

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                          // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
    [Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;          // Amount of maxSpeed applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%
    [Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;  // How much to smooth out the movement
    [SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = false;                         // Whether or not a player can steer while jumping;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                          // A mask determining what is ground to the character
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;                           // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_CeilingCheck;                          // A position marking where to check for ceilings
    [SerializeField] private Collider2D m_CrouchDisableCollider;                // A collider that will be disabled when crouching

    const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
    private bool m_Grounded;            // Whether or not the player is grounded.
    const float k_CeilingRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can stand up
    private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
    private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.
    private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;

    [Header("Events")]
    [Space]

    public UnityEvent OnLandEvent;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }

    public BoolEvent OnCrouchEvent;
    private bool m_wasCrouching = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (OnLandEvent == null)
            OnLandEvent = new UnityEvent();

        if (OnCrouchEvent == null)
            OnCrouchEvent = new BoolEvent();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bool wasGrounded = m_Grounded;
        m_Grounded = false;

        // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
        // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
            {
                m_Grounded = true;
                if (!wasGrounded)
                    OnLandEvent.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }


    public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
    {
        // If crouching, check to see if the character can stand up
        if (!crouch)
        {
            // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
            if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
            {
                crouch = true;
            }
        }

        //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
        if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
        {

            // If crouching
            if (crouch)
            {
                if (!m_wasCrouching)
                {
                    m_wasCrouching = true;
                    OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(true);
                }

                // Reduce the speed by the crouchSpeed multiplier
                move *= m_CrouchSpeed;

                // Disable one of the colliders when crouching
                if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                    m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Enable the collider when not crouching
                if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                    m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = true;

                if (m_wasCrouching)
                {
                    m_wasCrouching = false;
                    OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(false);
                }
            }

            // Move the character by finding the target velocity
            Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
            // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);

            // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
            if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
            // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
            else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
        }
        // If the player should jump...
        if (m_Grounded && jump)
        {
            // Add a vertical force to the player.
            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
        }
    }


    private void Flip()
    {
        // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
        m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

        // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

And here is the actual Character Movement Code -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController2D controller;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool jump = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, false, jump);
        jump = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the movement on android device is too small to be noticed. Try multiplying speed to delta time and then tweak the speed value to reach your desired movement speed.

```
rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x , direction.y) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Make sure the script is attached to the game object with Rigidbody2D component. Also if your computer doesn't support touch, you can use mouse input to have the same result on computer and mobile device.

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        touchPosition.z = 0;
        direction = (touchPosition - transform.position);
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x, direction.y) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

This code is also works on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Time.deltaTime` or increasing the force with `Time.deltaTime`.

Comment: Hmm. Code-only. Pity.